# Zoom in and out while using Locator() in R

Tags: r

I have an XY scatter plot of many points which define filament like structures (imagine looking at a pile of sticks laying on the ground, that's what these plots look like). I am using [Locator](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/graphics/html/locator.html/%20%22locator') to identify a start and end of each filament. The end result I get is a table of line segments defined by two points in XY.

A simplified base version of my code runs like this:

```
n=1
NumberOfFilaments=5
Xdata=rnorm(1000,mean=500,sd=100)
Ydata=rnorm(1000,mean=500,sd=100)
clicks.table=c()     

while (n<=NumberOfFilaments) {
  plot (Xdata,Ydata)
  clicks = locator(2)
  A = c(clicks$x[1],clicks$y[1])
  B = c(clicks$x[2],clicks$y[2])
  clickpoints = c(A,B)
  clicks.table = rbind(clicks.table,clickpoints)
  n=n+1
}
```

Some of my data sets have gotten quite large in regard to the total width of the data in X & Y in comparison to the length of the filaments I am trying to click on. This makes it hard for me to accurately click on the start and end of the filaments.  What I would like to be able to do is zoom in on the plot to view an individual filament, click two points then zoom out to view the whole pile again. I typically use R studio if that matters. Thank you in advance.

Comment: I don't think you can zoom into base plots while using a locator.

Comment: Your code is not reproduce-able.

Comment: @and I have added the initialization of a few variables so the code can be run by anyone without my data sets.